# VS Code opens file multiple Times by hitting F12

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am working on an Angular project and I'm using VS Code. I'm used to work with two panes open, on the left pane e.g. file.component.ts and on the right side file.component.html. When I want to use the "Go to definition" feature (F12) to jump from a method in html to the definition file it reopens another file.component.ts file in the same pane instead of switching to the file already open. I then have same file open twice.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the VS code options in this menu in MacBook:

[VScode GO option menu open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42OLC.png)

Try to check the the VScode keyboard shortcuts

[VSCode KeyBoard ShortsCut Menu In Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Lu6.png)

Hope it is help.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I'm looking for a way to not have the same file open twice or even more. This is very irritating.

Comment: On my mac the f12  dows nothing... if i want to go to definition i hit command+click

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Editor: Reveal If Open** setting (`workbench.editor.revealIfOpen`).

When set, if a file is already opened in an editor (in any group) then the existing instance is "revealed" (bring to focus) instead of opening a new editor.

I use it to avoid opening multiple instances of the same file when double-clicking in global search results, but it will work in your case too.